# Touchscreen technologies for outdoor use

Tags: displays, touchscreen

First of all - I must say that I am not a hardware expert, I am just a simple programmer, and I also not sure this is the right place for this question (but title of site suggest it might be).

I have tried to read a lot about touch screen technologies - but I am a bit in lost here . So many technologies (resistive, capacitive, OLED, PCAP, - everywhere I tried to search explain **how** they work, but I would not find condition based recommendations)

I wanted to know what types of touchscreen technology would be best for an outdoor kiosk, that can be potentially exposed to direct sun, dust or small debris, as well as rain?

My aim is to build some kind of a self-service "kiosk", the kind you often see at a metro station, or train station, or even ATM's, but this particular one would have to be placed in totally exposed outdoor areas.

I have already built a few prototypes, and totally excluded the IR types (any dust or debris on the edges would compromise performance).

The screen size would be around 17", and the preferred solution would be one that can be covered with 2-3mm tempered glass (meaning glass as top layer).

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question here. Are you asking for a specific touchscreen to use outside? Recommendations on what type of technology?

Comment: @enderland No.. not a specific touch screen `model` or `manufacturer`. I am asking   about `type` or `technology`.. see my original question again. there are many available technologies, all with pros and cons , and all with different types of implementations. I am searching a use specific technology to be adapted to a specific case use scenario . in my case - outdoors use .

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a resistive touch screen for outdoor/rugged devices. Resistive touch screens uses two sheets of non conductive material with conductive material in between the two sheets. When the sheet is pressed, a current is allowed through and a touch is registered. Unlike capacitive touch screens (found on most smartphones/tablets these days) it is more durable and can be used with gloved hands. The downside to this is that it is not super precise and will need calibration from time to time.

Comment: Citation needed for "it is more durable".

Comment: @Alpha3031 IDK? Experience?